# Is this some kind of Fenestraria?

Tags: identification, succulents

Is this a kind of Fenestraria? On the store label it says Lithops, but I've bought mis-labeled plants before.

[image]

Comment: Fenestram is Latin for window.  It's where this plant's Genus gets its name in reference to the clear widows at the apex of each "leaf".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, I think it probably is Fenestraria rather than Lithops, most likely F. rhopalophylla, image [here](http://www.succulentguide.com/graphics/f_rhopalophylla_b_600.jpg).

[image: F. rhopalophylla]

Comment: Thank you. Now I have to wait to see the colour of the flowers. If they will be white, it belongs to Fenestraria rhopalophylla subsp. rhopalophylla, if they will be yellow, it belongs to Fenestraria rhopalophylla subsp. aurantiaca. Using your answer I have checked on wikipedia and I have found that it also might be Frithia pulchra, bearing pink-mauve flowers. So I guess I have to wait for the flowers no matter what.

Comment: @AlinaMitroi - I'm pretty sure its not Frithia pulchra - the 'window' on the top of the stems is more heart shaped, and the stems are darker green. Otherwise,yep, could be one or other of the  subspecies of Fenestraria... its a nice plant, even if its not Lithops!